# How to group by consecutive dates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, python-requests

I have this data. I want to find which activity occurred consecutively for how many days:

```
    Id          datetime             date       Hour            Activity
0   Abc         2021-04-26 14:30:33  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login
1   Abc         2021-04-26 12:55:27  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login
2   Abc         2021-04-26 13:30:31  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login
3   Abc         2021-04-28 11:55:33  2021-04-28 (10.0, 12.0]    login
4   Abc         2021-05-01 08:25:15  2021-05-01 (8.0, 10.0]     login
5   Abc         2021-05-01 09:45:01  2021-05-01 (8.0, 10.0]     login
6   Abc         2021-05-02 11:05:19  2021-05-02 (10.0, 12.0]    login
7   Abc         2021-05-03 02:26:12  2021-05-03 (2.0, 4.0]      browsing
8   Abc         2021-05-03 03:59:10  2021-05-03 (2.0, 4.0]      browsing
9   Abc         2021-05-03 05:40:00  2021-05-03 (4.0, 6.0]      browsing
```

I tried grouping the all consecutive dates:

```
sample['Consecutive'] = sample.groupby('Id').date.diff().dt.days.ne(1).cumsum()
```

This giving me an output as:

```
    Id          datetime             date       Hour            Activity   Consecutive
0   Abc         2021-04-26 14:30:33  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login      1
1   Abc         2021-04-26 12:55:27  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login      2
2   Abc         2021-04-26 13:30:31  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login      3
3   Abc         2021-04-28 11:55:33  2021-04-28 (10.0, 12.0]    login      4
4   Abc         2021-05-01 08:25:15  2021-05-01 (8.0, 10.0]     login      5
5   Abc         2021-05-01 09:45:01  2021-05-01 (8.0, 10.0]     login      6
6   Abc         2021-05-02 11:05:19  2021-05-02 (10.0, 12.0]    login      6
7   Abc         2021-05-03 02:26:12  2021-05-03 (2.0, 4.0]      browsing   6 
8   Abc         2021-05-03 03:59:10  2021-05-03 (2.0, 4.0]      browsing   7
9   Abc         2021-05-03 05:40:00  2021-05-03 (4.0, 6.0]      browsing   8
```

Desired output:

```
    Id          datetime             date       Hour            Activity   Consecutive
0   Abc         2021-04-26 14:30:33  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login      1
1   Abc         2021-04-26 12:55:27  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login      1
2   Abc         2021-04-26 13:30:31  2021-04-26 (12.0, 14.0]    login      1
3   Abc         2021-04-28 11:55:33  2021-04-28 (10.0, 12.0]    login      2
4   Abc         2021-05-01 08:25:15  2021-05-01 (8.0, 10.0]     login      3
5   Abc         2021-05-01 09:45:01  2021-05-01 (8.0, 10.0]     login      3
6   Abc         2021-05-02 11:05:19  2021-05-02 (10.0, 12.0]    login      3
7   Abc         2021-05-03 02:26:12  2021-05-03 (2.0, 4.0]      browsing   3 
8   Abc         2021-05-03 03:59:10  2021-05-03 (2.0, 4.0]      browsing   3
9   Abc         2021-05-03 05:40:00  2021-05-03 (4.0, 6.0]      browsing   3
```

Please help me in correcting this.

Comment: why would you groupby with Id, if all the Ids are same?

Comment: @edusanketdk This is just a sample data I have other Ids too.

Comment: Why is `login` on `2021-05-02` not 4? And why does `browsing` not reset the counter if you want consecutive days per activity?

Comment: @perl Sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: @Pri in row 6 in expected output you have Consecutive=3, but should it not be 4 (the dates before it are 2021-04-26, 2021-04-28, 2021-05-01)

Comment: And then starting from row 7 you have activity=browsing. Do you not want to reset Consecutive to 0 for each activity?

Comment: @perl No, right now I just want to find if the particular person is active continuously for how many days?

Comment: OK, please see my answer and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly what you're trying to achieve, you just need to change `ne(1)` to `gt(1)`:

```
df['Consecutive'] = df.groupby('Id')['date'].diff().dt.days.gt(1).cumsum() + 1
df
```

Output:

```
    Id             datetime       date          Hour  Activity  Consecutive
0  Abc  2021-04-26 14:30:33 2021-04-26  (12.0, 14.0]     login            1
1  Abc  2021-04-26 12:55:27 2021-04-26  (12.0, 14.0]     login            1
2  Abc  2021-04-26 13:30:31 2021-04-26  (12.0, 14.0]     login            1
3  Abc  2021-04-28 11:55:33 2021-04-28  (10.0, 12.0]     login            2
4  Abc  2021-05-01 08:25:15 2021-05-01   (8.0, 10.0]     login            3
5  Abc  2021-05-01 09:45:01 2021-05-01   (8.0, 10.0]     login            3
6  Abc  2021-05-02 11:05:19 2021-05-02  (10.0, 12.0]     login            3
7  Abc  2021-05-03 02:26:12 2021-05-03    (2.0, 4.0]  browsing            3
8  Abc  2021-05-03 03:59:10 2021-05-03    (2.0, 4.0]  browsing            3
9  Abc  2021-05-03 05:40:00 2021-05-03    (4.0, 6.0]  browsing            3
```

Comment: I want the same consecutive values for all the consecutive days.  please check my desired output again.

Comment: @Pri OK, I think I see what you mean now, please see the updated answer